# Force colliding labels but not their points in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to make a line chart that has to support up to 100 points on it, making it very crowded. The problem is that some of the labels overlap.

The method I was trying involved drawing all the points, then separately drawing all the labels and running a force collision on the labels to stop them overlapping, then after the force collision drawing a line between each of the labels and their associated point.

I can't make the forces work, let alone the drawing of lines after.

Any suggestions for a better way to do this are heartily welcomed also.

Here is my code:

```
$.each(data.responseJSON.responsedata, function(k, v) {
    var thispoint = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+pointx+","+pointy+")");
    thispoint.append("circle").attr("r", 10).style("fill","darkBlue").style("stroke","black");
    var label = svg.append("text").text(v.conceptName).style("text-anchor", "end").attr("font-family", "Calibri");
    label.attr("transform", "translate("+(pointx)+","+(pointy-12)+") rotate(90)")
    });
nodes = d3.selectAll("text")

simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(10))
        .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(10))
        .force("collide",d3.forceCollide(20).strength(5))
        .velocityDecay(0.15);

ticks = 0;

simulation.nodes(data)
    .on("tick", d => {
        ticks = ticks + 1;
        d3.select(this).attr("x", function(d) { return d.x }).attr("y", function(d) { return d.x });
        console.log("updated" + this)
    });
```

Comment: In the `"tick"` listener, don't use an arrow function if you want `this` to be the DOM element. Change it to a regular function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force layout is a relatively expensive way of moving labels to avoid collision. It is iteratively and computationally intensive.

More efficient algorithms add the labels one at a time, determining the best position for each. For example a 'greedy' strategy adds each label in sequence, selecting the position where the label has the lowest overlap with already added labels.

I've created a D3 components, d3fc-label-layout, that implements a number of label layout strategies:

https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc-label-layout

[image]

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
  // Use the text label component for each datapoint. This component renders both
  // a text label and a circle at the data-point origin. For this reason, we don't
  // need to use a scatter / point series.
  const labelPadding = 2;
  const textLabel = fc.layoutTextLabel()
    .padding(2)
    .value(d => d.language);

  // a strategy that combines simulated annealing with removal
  // of overlapping labels
  const strategy = fc.layoutRemoveOverlaps(fc.layoutGreedy());

  // create the layout that positions the labels
  const labels = fc.layoutLabel(strategy)
    .size((d, i, g) => {
      // measure the label and add the required padding
      const textSize = g[i].getElementsByTagName('text')[0].getBBox();
      return [
        textSize.width,
        textSize.height
      ];
    })
    .position((d) => {
      return [
        d.users,
                d.orgs
      ]
    })
    .component(textLabel);
```

https://bl.ocks.org/ColinEberhardt/27508a7c0832d6e8132a9d1d8aaf231c

Comment: GitHub link is broken